# Assignment: Earth

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

I was up late last night and came across ST-TOS Assignment:Earth.

I missed the first few minutes of it and online googles have fallen short on what I want to know.

How did the Enterprise get thrown back in time to 1968?  I thought the whole time travel thing was usually a mistake of some sort but it seemed totally natural that they were back in 1968 in this episode.  They didn't even have a clip of how they get back to their normal time.  It was like another day at the office.

What gives?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was in the [opening teaser for the episode](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Assignment%3a_Earth_%28episode%29#Teaser) (bolding mine):

> "Captain's log. **Using the light-speed breakaway factor**, the Enterprise
>   has moved back through time to the 20th century. We are now in
>   extended orbit around Earth, using our ship's deflector shields to
>   remain unobserved. **Our mission – historical research**. We are
>   monitoring Earth communications to find out how our planet survived
>   desperate problems in the year 1968."

So yes, they *intentionally* went back in time.  In TOS 1x21, [Tomorrow is Yesterday](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Tomorrow_is_Yesterday_%28episode%29), (the episode that they discovered the light-speed breakaway version of time travel), they also figured out how to reverse it.

Presumably, they assumed that viewers would know they used the same method to return to their own time, and didn't bother putting it in the episode.  [Assignment Earth](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Assignment%3a_Earth_%28episode%29) is episode 2x26, over a season later.

Comment: Good thing they stayed away from those pesky Apollo flights!

Comment: They accidentally discovered the time warp in "Tomorrow is Yesterday" (Season 1, Episode 19, aired 1967-01-26). "Assignment Earth was Season 2, Episode 26, last episode of the season, aired 1968-03-29.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yeah, I said they were different episodes, but I see it wasn't very clear.  Updated the answer to include links and season/episode numbers.

Answer (score 3):

The last episode of the second season: Assignment Earth was doing double duty as an episode of Star Trek and the pilot of another series spin off called *Assignment Earth.*

> The show would have featured actor Robert Lansing as Gary Seven, a
>   futuristic "James Bond," as the lead character. The episode stars Teri
>   Garr as Roberta Lincoln, who would have been a co-star in the series,
>   had it continued on its own. --[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment:_Earth)

The strange part of this episode was the fact the ship was doing "historical research" by traveling back in time! They talk about it in a matter of fact fashion as if it were something they did every day.

The slingshot effect was not even SHOWN. The show opens with them in the past intercepting Gary Seven's solar system ranged transporter beam!

They also gave a shout out to the sonic screwdriver. It's how Gary 7 escapes from the brig.

[image]

Comment: Did some research and both devices were introduced within days of each other. An awesome coincidence. First appearance of the sonic screwdriver in *Doctor Who: 
Fury from the Deep - Part 1* first aired on 16 March 1968, first airing of the *Assignment Earth* episode: 
March 29, 1968.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is likely to get closed as general reference, since the answer is readily available on Wikipedia.

This episode was done as the lead-in to an intended spin-off series.  Gary 7, his cat, and Teri Garr's character were supposed to go on to their own show, so the emphasis was on setting that up, not on Kirk/Spock/etc. having adventures.

In Kirk's log dictation, he just says something like "we used a gravitational slingshot maneuver to go back in time to investigate..." and, as you say, they didn't even bother showing them going back to their correct time.